# Wrong focus with ionic 3 ion-input

Tags: ionic-framework, angular2-forms

I'm creating a simple form with ionic 3 but I get a wrong focus position on the very first ion-input. Here is a screenshot of the problem :

[image]

You can see that the blue cursor is not positioned on the ion-input. But my code seems to be ok :

```
<ion-content padding> 
    <ion-list>
        <ion-item>
            <ion-label stacked>Username</ion-label>
            <ion-input type="text" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" [(ngModel)]="username" placeholder="Your Username"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item>
            <ion-label stacked>Other Username</ion-label>
            <ion-input type="text" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" [(ngModel)]="snap_username" placeholder="Your Other Username"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

Anyone knows a solution to this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like I found the solution.

If it can help someone, the issue disappeared after I installed [the WKWebview plugin](https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-plugin-ionic-webview#installation-instructions).